# can I have a sandbox on developer edition?

Tags: force.com, sandbox, developer-edition

I'm working on a developer edition of force.com
do I have any access to the sandbox?or it's accessible only for professional or unlimited editions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sandboxes are only available on Professional Edition and higher for the included price of licenses. All other editions, including Contact Manager, Group, and Developer, cannot have or purchase Sandboxes.

Comment: Professional Edition now gets 10 free sandboxes. However, since they don't have API access, they can't deploy anything from them.

Comment: @crmprogdev You can still use Change Sets, though, right? So it's not entirely useless. I'll update the answer, although it's still pretty much the same from the OP's point.

Comment: No, you can't use Change Sets. That requires API access. You can test things out, including building new Processes, but then have to recreate the Process in the production org.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* have a sandbox on a [Trial edition](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales.jsp). Of course the whole shooting match goes *poof* after 30 days, so I don't know that it will do a while lot of good for most use cases.